# Python/tkinter: elapsed time in label/updating a label constantly?

Tags: python, loops, audio, tkinter, label

So im trying to write code to display the playback time of an audio file, by constantly looping and updating the label text from pyglet's elapsed time method. I can get the time to appear, but it does not update. was wondering how to update the label on the GUI to show the elapsed time? The loop for time is near the bottom, i provided all the code just in case though.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import pyglet
import pyglet.media as media
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import colorchooser


#make player and it's methods global
global player
player = pyglet.media.Player();

app = Tk()
app.title("Music PYlayer")
app.geometry("600x200")
have_avbin = True 



#opens file 
def openFile():
    global f
    f =  filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Mp3 files", "*.mp3"),("Wav files", "*.wav"),("All files","*.*")))

def aColor():
     mycolor = colorchooser.askcolor()
     color_name = mycolor[1] #  #to pick up the color name in HTML notation, i.e. the 2nd element of the tuple returned by the colorchooser
     app.configure(background=color_name)


#Creates menu bar for opening MP3s, and closing the program
menu = Menu(app)
file = Menu(menu)
file.add_command(label='Open', command=  openFile) # replace 'print' with the name of your open function
file.add_command(label='Background color', command = aColor)
file.add_command(label='Exit', command=app.destroy) # closes the tkinter window, ending the app
menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file)
app.config(menu=menu)

#Run each app library mainloop in different python thread to prevent freezing
def playMusic():
    global player_thread
    player_thread = Thread(target=real_playMusic)
    player_thread.start()

def stopMusic():
    global player_thread
    player_thread = Thread(target=real_stopMusic)
    player_thread.start()

#Play open file function attached to button
def real_playMusic():
    src=pyglet.media.load(f, streaming=False)
    global player
    player = pyglet.media.Player();
    player.queue(src)
    player.play()
    pyglet.app.run()

#Stop the music function
def real_stopMusic():
     player.pause()




#Play button creation
btnPlay = Button(app, text ="Play", command = playMusic)
btnPlay.place(x=75,y=100)


#Pause button creation
btnPause = Button(app)
btnPause.configure(text = "Stop", command = stopMusic)
btnPause.place(x=475,y=100)



#Time readout for track
def ReadOut():
    time2 = player.time
    i=0
    if i <= 0:
        nowPlaying=Label(app, text=time2)
        nowPlaying.grid()
        app.update_idletasks()





ReadOut()
app.mainloop() # keep at the end
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of updating it with a loop, we're going to have that function tell the root `tkinter` instance (`app`) to call it again after a certain amount of time, with the `after()` method. In this way, it'll run indefinitely with the specified frequency. This is similar to recursion, but the function completes each time it runs instead of waiting for the recursive calls to end, so it won't run into the recursion limit.

We will also create the `Label` only once, and then simply reconfigure it.

Change this:

```
#Time readout for track
def ReadOut():
    time2 = player.time
    i=0
    if i <= 0:
        nowPlaying=Label(app, text=time2)
        nowPlaying.grid()
        app.update_idletasks()

ReadOut()
app.mainloop() # keep at the end
```

to this:

```
#Time readout for track

nowPlaying = Label(app, text='') # create the Label
nowPlaying.grid() # and grid it

def ReadOut(widget, player): # take a widget and a Player
    widget.config(text=player.time) # reconfigure the widget with player.time
    app.update_idletasks() # I don't know if this is necessary -
    # try taking it out and see what happens

    # this will call this function again after 200ms,
    # passing it the same widget and player.
    # we use a lambda to more easily pass arguments to the function
    app.after(200, lambda: ReadOut(widget, player))

ReadOut(nowPlaying, player) # call the function and pass it the Label and the Player
app.mainloop() # keep at the end
```

Comment: Can you describe the failure in more detail?